# flutter share image or widget directly to social media?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver

I am doing apps which require option to share an image or widget as an image directly to social media like Facebook,whats app.. etc. For flutter there is package called "share 0.5.3" but this package only share the text alone as below,

```
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');
```

please suggest me any method to achieve this and i am not interested any third party package to use my apps.

Comment: flutter doesn't support to share media file officially, so if you "aren't interested any third party package to use in your apps", you can try to write the plugin yourself: https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Good luck bro!

Comment: downvoting for the "i am not interested any third party package to use my apps."